# Angularjs: data binding not successful

Tags: angularjs

In a angularjs project, I want get user data from rails server and then use data. For this, I have a `record.js` and `sessionService.js`. I send request from `record.js` to `sessionService.js` and then recieve response.

I put `js` file and echo of data  below:

`record.js`:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app');

app.controller('RecordCtrl',['$scope','Session','Records',function($scope, Session, Records){
    $scope.user = Session.requestCurrentUser();
    //echo $scope.user:
    //[object Object] 
}]);
```

`sessionService.js`:

```
    'use strict';
    angular.module('sessionService', [])
    .factory('Session', function($location, $http, $q) {
            requestCurrentUser: function() {
                if (service.isAuthenticated()) {
                    return $q.when(service.currentUser);
                    //echo service.currentUser:
                    //Object {then: function, catch: function, finally: function}
                    //catch: function (a){return this.then(null,a)}
                    //arguments: (...)
                    //get arguments: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }
                    //set arguments: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }
                    //caller: (...)
                    //get caller: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }
                    //set caller: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }
                    //length: 1
                    //name: ""
                    //prototype: Object
                    //constructor: function (a){return this.then(null,a)}
                    //__proto__: Object
                    //__proto__: function Empty() {}
                    //<function scope>
                    //finally: function (a){function b(a,c){var d=e();c?d.resolve(a):d.reject(a);return d.promise}function d(e,f){var g=null;try{g=
    //then: function (b,f,h){var m=e(),I=function(d){try{m.resolve((P(b)?b:c)(d))}catch(e){m.reject(e),a(e)}},y=function(b){try{m.resolve((P(f)?f:d)(b))}catch(c){m.reject(c),a(c)}},F=function(b){try{m.notify((P(h)?h:c)(b))}catch(d){a(d)}};g?g.push([I,y,F]):l.then(I,y,F);return m.promise}
                    //__proto__: Object


        } else {
                    return $http.get('/api/users').then(function(response) {
                        service.currentUser = response.data.user;
                        return service.currentUser;
                        //echo service.currentUser:
                        //Object {id: 2, email: "mgh@mgh.com", created_at: "2014-08-11T08:37:59.981Z", updated_at: "2014-08-25T09:24:53.919Z"} 
                    });
                }
            },

            currentUser: null,

            isAuthenticated: function(){
                return !!service.currentUser;
            }
        };
        return service;
    });
```

I don't know why I can get and see data in `sessionService`, but I can't recieve data in `record.js` and use it. How can I fixed this problem?

Edit: Add `app.js`:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app',['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'sessionService', 'recordService'])
        .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
            var interceptor = ['$location', '$rootScope', '$q', function($location, $rootScope, $q) {
                function success(response) {
                    return response
                };

                function error(response) {
                    if (response.status == 401) {
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('event:unauthorized');
                        scope.$apply(function() { $location.path("/route"); });
                        console.log('app 401');
                        $location.path('/users/login');
//                        $window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
                        return response;
                    };
                    return $q.reject(response);
                };

                return function(promise) {
                    return promise.then(success, error);
                };
            }];

//            $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
        }])
        .config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
            $routeProvider
                    .when('/',               {controller: 'HomeCtrl',    templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('templates/index.html') %>'})
                    .when('/record',         {controller: 'RecordCtrl',  templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('templates/record/index.html') %>'})
                    .when('/users/login',    {controller: 'UsersCtrl',   templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('templates/users/login.html') %>'})
                    .when('/users/register', {controller: 'UsersCtrl',   templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('templates/users/register.html') %>'})
                    .otherwise(              {redirectTo: '/'});
        }]);
```

Comment: I don't see where `service` is declared. What is it ?

Comment: I have an `app.js` and delare all of dependency on this.

Comment: Can you show us this app.js, maybe there are dependency issues in it as suggested by Jai ?

Comment: I edit question and add `app.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you need to include the dependencies in the module level:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['sessionService']);
```

I think you have two different modules and you need the data in other module then you need to provide the dependencies.

As you have defined `Session` factory in other file with different module and you are accessing in other file with different module, so if you want to have access the methods of other module then you need to pass the dependencies in the array part of module syntax.

Comment: I asked new question, Can you read it?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501458/angularjs-add-service-to-angular-module/