# Angularjs: add service to angular.module

Tags: angularjs

I want use a service in a angular.module.

I have a `record.js` for `RecordCtrl` and I want use `requestCurrentUser` fnction that exist in `sessionService.js`. I use `Session` for pass data between controller and service. I send a request from `record,js` by `requestCurrentUser` function like below:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller('RecordCtrl',['$scope','Session','Records',function($scope, Session, Records){
    $scope.user = Session.requestCurrentUser();
}]);
```

and I recieve this in `sessionService.js` like below:

```
  'use strict';
   angular.module('sessionService', [])
    .factory('Session', function($location, $http, $q) {
        var service = {

            requestCurrentUser: function() {
                    return $http.get('/api/users').then(function(response) {
                        service.currentUser = response.data.user;
                        return service.currentUser;
                    );
                }
            },
            currentUser: null,
        return service;
    });
```

I can get data correctly in `requestCurrentUser`, but I cannot recieve this data in `record.js`. When I echo data in `sessionService.js`, I can see below data:

```
Object {id: 2, email: "mgh@mgh.com", created_at: "2014-08-11T08:37:59.981Z", updated_at: "2014-08-26T08:03:27.702Z"}
```

But I cannot recieve this data in `record.js` and I get an empty object like below:

```
[object Object]
```

I think the problem of code is about `Session` that I use in 2 `js` file(`record.js` and `sessionService.js`). For add dependency, I have  a `app.js` that include dependencies on this.

`app.js`:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('app',['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'sessionService', 'recordService'])
```

I cannot find the problem, I add `sessionService.js` to `record.js` by below code:

```
app.service('sessionService');
```

But the problem isn't fix. I don't know how can I resolve this problem? Any one have idea for fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be fixed as follows:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller('RecordCtrl',['$scope','Session','Records',function($scope, Session, Records){
    Session.requestCurrentUser().then(function(data) {
        $scope.user = data;
    });

}]);
```

Comment: I return `currentUser` to `requestCurrentUser` function. This is no problem. I use your guide, but I get `undefined` error when I echo `$scope.user`.

Comment: I find another solution, but your guide is shorter and easier and work fine. Another solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088153/how-to-http-synchronous-call-with-angularjs